# Zend Framework Image upload Error : The given destination is not writeable

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form, lamp

```
//Default Image with article
    $imgElement = new Zend_Form_Element_File('imgElement');
    $imgElement->setLabel("Upload an Image:");
    $imgElement->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH."/../upload/articleImg/");      
    $imgElement->addValidator('Count',false,1); //ensure only 1 file
    $imgElement->addValidator('Size',false,102400); //limit to 100K
    $imgElement->addValidator('Extension',false,'jpg,png,gif');
    $this->addElement($imgElement);
```

Above is my code to upload a file along with the article.
The error I get is

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:
Message: The given destination is not writeable
```

If I do an `ls -l` , I get `drwxrwxr-x 3 aman aman 4096 Jul 31 20:03 upload`

I have permission to write to that dir. If I use terminal and mv some file to that location it goes through. I think my application might not have the access to write to that dir maybe ?

Is this a bug or something ?
I tried this too. But didn't work

```
//Default Image with article
    $destination = APPLICATION_PATH."/../upload/articleImg";
    chmod($destination ,0777);

    $imgElement = new Zend_Form_Element_File('imgElement');
    $imgElement->setLabel("Upload an Image:");
    $imgElement->setDestination($destination);      
    $imgElement->addValidator('Count',false,1); //ensure only 1 file
    $imgElement->addValidator('Size',false,102400); //limit to 100K
    $imgElement->addValidator('Extension',false,'jpg,png,gif');
    $this->addElement($imgElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this link : https://serversforhackers.com/permissions-users/

Apparently I had to grant the access to the web user i.e. www-data. Followed the steps below.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data aman
sudo chgrp www-data /home/aman/Work/aman_proj
chmod g+rwxs /home/aman/Work/aman_proj
```

Thanks for help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

in your hosting control panel, you need to set the file permissions for that folder so it is writable.

Go to the control panel's file explorer and change it in there.

-OR-

If it is your local copy, you need to set the permissions through your OS.

in unix, linux, mac, this is:

```
chmod 777 ./upload
```

(from within the public/images/ folder)

In windows I think you either just right click the upload folder -> properties and un-tick read only. Either that or set the permissions in sharing and security options.

Comment: Its a local copy and I am using ubuntu, and when I do an ls -l, this is the permission for that dir => drwxrwxr-x . So it seems like its writable, right ?

Comment: i never used Ubounto so i don't know how to change permissions but i found this useful page on their comunity website. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver is probably not running under the user or group `aman` for which the write permissions are set on the upload folder. 
Either change the owner (`www-data` is default on ubuntu) of the folder

```
chown -R www-data ./upload
```

or give it global write permissions

```
chmod -R 777 ./upload
```

I would recommend the first solution.
The `-R` is optional and changes also permissions on subfolders of your `upload` folder, if required.